# Navbar is not responding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar with some items, but when I click on it, nothing happens. In the console of the Chrome, isn't showing any error.

I added the tags as the [bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) asks.

Someone have any idea of what's wrong?

Above is my _Layout.cshtml code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>p.align{padding-left: 2em }</style>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - PakaPaka Store</title>

    <environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/site.css"/>
    </environment>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand"> <img src=@ViewBag.Logo height="50"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Site" asp-action="Index">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Dash" asp-action="Products">Produtos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Site" asp-action="Contact">Contato</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <footer>
            <hr />
            <p class="align">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/pakapaka.store/">
                    <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pakapaka.store/">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </p>
            <p class="align">&copy; 2018 - Desenvolvido por: Hatsumi Higuchi Hashinaga</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/Content/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing is a .Net Core way. Using .Net Framework you can use an specific syntax to define links to controllers, like so:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

For more info you can check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view).